# validate form first then do ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

Im using a jquery validation plugin to validate my form. But there are still some fields that need custom validation.

The strange thing is. When submiting it checks my select box validation first when this is OK then all field turn red because of the $.validate(); if nothing is filled in but still it proceeds with the ajax call...... why is this?

also Im using this plugin: http://formvalidator.net/#configuration i have tried the callbacks but for some reason it still not returns false and proceeds with ajax.

```
$( "#registration-form" ).submit(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();

    $.validate();

    //Check dropdown
    if(document.getElementById('foodassoonas').selectedIndex == 0)
    {
    $('#dateerrormsg').html('not ok');
    $("#foodassoonas").css({"border":"1px solid red"});
    return false;
    }


    $.post(jssitebaseUrl+'/ajaxFile.php',{'contactemail':contactemail,'action':'checkOrderEmailId'}, function(output){

        alert(output);
        if(output == 'already' && contactpassword !=""){
            $("#createUserError").addClass('errClass1 margin0');

            $("#createUserError").html('not ok');
            $("#createUserError").show();
            return false;
        }else if(output == 'gotopayment' || (output == 'already' && contactpassword =="")){
            document.checkoutform.submit();
        }
        return false;
    });


return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 $.validate({
        onError : function() {
      alert('Validation failed');
      return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: if i add return before the method, when clicking submit all the forms that are atached to the plugin work.... but then the ajax and custom drop down validation does not work... it just submits after fixing all the fields for the validation plugin

Comment: first it shows the dropdown error if i set that.. then all validation inputs turn red of validation plugin and allerts the error.. then when clicking OK it alerts the ajax and still proceeds

Comment: i have also set it seperate from eachother the validate in seperate <script> removed it from onsubmit function... same thing happening.... all validation error show... but after setting the dropdown to a good var... it shows all the validation errors but then alerts the ajax and proceeds

Comment: Ok now if i click submit it shows all errors of validation module. THen i fill in all errors and click submit again. Then no errors show but form also does not proceed. Also.. the custom error of dropdown also not shows...

Answer (score 0):

After playing with it i got it sort of working by doing this:

```
>>>> REMOVED (PLACED ON BOTTOM) event.preventDefault();
$( "#registration-form" ).submit(function( event ) {

var flag = $.validate(); 
if(!flag) { 

    //Check dropdown
    if(document.getElementById('foodassoonas').selectedIndex == 0)
    {
    $('#dateerrormsg').html('U heeft geen bezorgtijd aangegeven');
    $("#foodassoonas").css({"border":"1px solid red"});
    return false;
    }


var contactemail = $('#contactemail').val();
$.post(jssitebaseUrl+'/ajaxFile.php',{'contactemail':contactemail,'action':'checkOrderEmailId'}, function(output){

    alert(output);
    if(output == 'already' && contactpassword !=""){
        $("#createUserError").addClass('errClass1 margin0');

        $("#createUserError").html('not ok');
        $("#createUserError").show();
        return false;
    }else if(output == 'gotopayment' || (output == 'already' && contactpassword =="")){
        document.checkoutform.submit();
    }
    return false;
});

return flag; 
}



>>>> REMOVED return false;
>>>> ADDED event.preventDefault();
});
```

only now the ajax is not fired :(