# Form Validator with ajax() call doesn't perform validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I'm using this [form validator](http://formvalidator.net/) and an `ajax();` call to fill in an overlay that will then be displayed, after confirming if an email exists in our database. The php file will determine if the registration or login forms will be displayed.

My current problem is, upon arrival if someone clicks the submit button (without filling anything in) the ajax call will be made and validation skipped. Although safety measures are in place I would rather have the visitor test his email before going to a registration form, in case he's already a user.

I've tested this several different ways, but none seem to work.

Misc functions:

```
//turn overlay on/off
function overlayOff() {$("#olContainer").html('');$('#overlay').css({ "display":"none" });}
function overlayOn() {$('#overlay').css({ "display":"block" });}
```

Ajax call:

```
//ajax call
function loadLoginFormOverlay(form) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Stop form from submitting normally 
    $("#olContainer").html('');    //Clear result div
    var values = form.serialize();    // Get some values from elements on the page: 
    $.ajax({    // Send the data using post and put the results in a div 
        url: "../inc/formLogin.php",
        type: "post",
        data: values,
        success: function(){
            $("#olContainer").load('../inc/formLogin.php');
            overlayOn();
        },
        error:function(){
            $("#olContainer").html('An error occurred while submitting your email, please refresh your browser and try again.<br>We are sorry for the inconvenience.');
            $("#olContainer").append('<input name="Close" type="submit" class="buttsubmit" id="olCloseBtn" value="Close" title="Close" />');
            overlayOn();
        }
    });
}
```

Binds:

```
//binding the submit event to the ajax call
$("#preLoginForm").submit(function(event) {
loadLoginFormOverlay($(this));
});

$("#clientForm").submit(function(event) {
loadLoginFormOverlay($(this));
});
```

Validation:

```
//executes validation
$.validate({
    form : '#preLoginForm, #clientForm',// Header preLoginForm && clientForm validation and AJAX call on success eventHandler
    modules: 'security, location', // security for email confirmation, location for country suggestion
    onModulesLoaded : function() {
        $('input[name="clCountry"]').suggestCountry(); //activate country suggestion
    },
    onError : function() {
        return false; //event.preventDefault();
    },
    onSuccess : function() {
        return false;//event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

I have tried placing the submit event binds inside the `onSuccess` event produced by validation, but the ajax call won't happen. [Found someone with the same problem, not solved.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19731621/1067465)

I've tried using a boolean that would be false until the `onSuccess` event fired, assigning it to true, but that required 2clicks to recognize the altered value.

I've tried assigning the validation to a variable, so it would serve as part of a conditional statement.

And I've ran out of ideas, can anyone please save me? xD
Oh, I've also googled plenty, but I think the crawler is sick :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've finally done something that actually has the effect I wanted. Although I feel the AJAX call should be able to be called from within the `onSuccess` event of the validation, so it would only be triggered if the validation was successful, any ideas on that are welcome.

What I did, basically was testing for an existing email on the input's value, within the submit bind. This way the button won't work without a value. (The validation does account for the required parameter, but isn't working as I expected)

Code changed:

```
$("#preLoginForm").submit(function(event) {
    if ($("#preLoginEmail").val()=="") {
        return false;
    } else {    
        loadLoginFormOverlay($(this));
        return false;
    }
});

$("#clientForm").submit(function(event) {
    if ($("input[name='clEmail']").val()=="" && $("input[name='clEmail_confirmation']").val()=="") {
        return false;
    } else {    
        loadLoginFormOverlay($(this));
        return false;
    }
});
```

If someone finds an easier way to do this, or can explain why I had to go through this process to get this result, I would appreciate it.